Discord.py slash command private reply
I have just worked out how to run a slash command using my Discord bot. However, I want the bot to reply to the user in a way that only they can see the message (Example below).
enter image description here
I have searched far and wide and I am unable to find any documentation on this. Could anyone give me a hand please? My code is attached below:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime

# Define the ping command

@commands.hybrid_command(name='ping', description='Fetch the bots ping')
async def ping(ctx):
    # Send "Calculating ping..." as part of the embed
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Calculating ping...", color=discord.Color.blue())
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    # Simulate a delay (you can adjust the delay time as needed)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)  # Wait for 1 second

    # Calculate latency
    latency = round(ctx.bot.latency * 1000)  # Convert latency to milliseconds

    # Update the embed to display the latency
    embed.title = "Pong!"
    embed.description = f'Latency: {latency}ms'
    embed.color = discord.Color.green()

    # Add a footer with the text "Internal Audio" and a timestamp with the current system time
    embed.set_footer(text="Internal Audio")
    embed.timestamp = datetime.now()  # Use datetime.now() to get the current system time

    # Edit the message to display the updated embed
    await msg.edit(embed=embed)
‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎‎ 


You can make the message which you can "dismiss" by adding the argument:
ephemeral = True

Therefore you code should look like this when you send the message:
 msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed, ephemeral = True)

Sadly, I am not 100% sure if this works with Hybrid Commands but it sure does with Interactions from the app_commands libary.
I hope I could help you! If it does not work, then it is sadly not possible with Hybrid Commands and you would need to make your slash commands with the app_command Libary (which I prefer).
